# Stop login state from changing in homepage with React Context

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-context, react-state-management

I tried to manage my app's login state with React context. The logic is simple: if the user passes the authentication in the login page, the login state in context should be updated to `true`, and the user will be directed to the homepage. I'm also using the login state and `Redirect` to prevent users from accessing the login page.

Unfortunately, this method failed to block logged-in users from viewing the login page. The reason is that the login state changed back to `false` once the user successfully logged in and get redirected here. I feel like I must be doing something wrong but could not figure it out.

Here is my **React Context** setup:

```
// LoginContext.js    
export default React.createContext({
    isAuthenticated: null,
    logoutUser: () => {},
    loginUser: () => {}
})
```

Here's the app component where I put Context provider:

```
//App.js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    isAuthenticated: false
  };

  logoutUser = () => {
    this.setState({ accessToken: null, username: null, isAuthenticated: false });
  };

 loginUser = () => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true })
  }

render() {
    const value = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      logoutUser: this.logoutUser,
      loginUser: this.loginUser
    }
    return (
      <LoginContext.Provider value={value}>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact path="/"
              render={() => (
                <HomePageScreen
                  data={homepage_data}
                  recordImpression={this.recordImpression}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route path="/login">
              {value.isAuthenticated
                ? <Redirect to="/" />
                : <LoginScreen
                  handleLoginFormSubmit={this.handleLoginFormSubmit}
                  recordImpression={this.recordImpression}
                />}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
     </LoginContext.Provider>
}
```

Here is the function that handles form submit and page transition in the **login page**:

```
  handleLoginFormSubmit = async (data, bannerID = '') => {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}/users/login`;
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(url, data)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ accessToken: res.data.access_token, username: data.username });
          this.loginUser()
          this.props.history.push('/', { newLogin: true });
          // the line below saves the refresh_token to the local storage of the browser
          window.localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", res.data.refresh_token);
          window.localStorage.setItem("username", data.username);
        })
    } catch (error) {
      if (bannerID) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        this.displayBanner(bannerID)
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

What if another state variable is declared in context which can keep track weather the redirect is happening for the first time or redirect happened already?